# PHP find positions of all occurrences of a particular word in a string

Tags: php, regex, arrays, substring, words

This is slightly different to finding all the positions of a substring inside a string because I want it to work with words which may be followed by a space, comma, semi-colon, colon, fullstop, exclamation mark and other punctuation.

I have the following function to find all the positions of a substring:

```
function strallpos($haystack,$needle,$offset = 0){ 
    $result = array(); 
    for($i = $offset; $i<strlen($haystack); $i++){ 
        $pos = strpos($haystack,$needle,$i); 
        if($pos !== FALSE){ 
            $offset =  $pos; 
            if($offset >= $i){ 
                $i = $offset; 
                $result[] = $offset; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return $result; 
}
```

Problem is, if I try to find all positions of the substring "us", it will return positions of the occurrence in "prospectus" or "inclusive" etc..

Is there any way to prevent this? Possibly using regular expressions?

Thanks.
Stefan

Comment: Try this http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: It doesn't return the positions of the found matches.

Comment: [str_word_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) with a format argument of `2`; followed by an [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) on the word you want to check would be an alternative to regexp

Comment: @StefanDunn, so you say your $needle should be something like "' ' . $needle . ' '" - no need to say that a pregmatch in combination with strpos would be better, thought.

Comment: It would probably be easier to just do what you were planning do with the positions, rather than trying to find those positions. For example, if you were planning to insert a tag there, just replace `$needle` with `<tag>$needle</tag>`. That could be easily done with regex. Of course, I don't know what you're trying to do, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: I would like the search to exclude words which appear in the middle of other words such as "to" in "into", "towards", "tomorrow". Instead I want it to only return the positions of the word "to" on its own.

Comment: It's for a search function to find occurrences of a word in a post.

Comment: What were you planning to do with the positions of the occurrences, once you found them? Maybe there's a better way to accomplish your ultimate goal.

Comment: I'm merging excerpts in a close proximity to create a google style search result excerpt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to demonstrate a non regexp alternative

```
$string = "It behooves us all to offer the prospectus for our inclusive syllabus";
$filterword = 'us';

$filtered = array_filter(
    str_word_count($string,2),
    function($word) use($filterword) {
        return $word == $filterword;
    }
);
var_dump($filtered);
```

where the keys of $filtered are the offset position

If you want case-insensitive, replace

```
return $word == $filterword;
```

with

```
return strtolower($word) == strtolower($filterword);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can capture offset with preg_match_all:

```
$str = "Problem is, if I try to find all positions of the substring us, it will return positions of the occurrence in prospectus or inclusive us us";
preg_match_all('/\bus\b/', $str, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($m);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => us
                    [1] => 60
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => us
                    [1] => 134
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => us
                    [1] => 137
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Good solution bro.